# How to I can select a line of text in browser screen by webdriver to use keyboard or mouse?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I want to use ChromeDriver to select a line of text in browser screen and change style. for example click to bold button in editor toolbar.

for example, its my html code.

> `<p id="boldId">bold </p>`

I attached image.[image]

Comment: You would need to use the `JavascriptExecutor` class and a `Javascript` snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to create text selection, set formatting and get HTML result?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://haixing-hu.github.io/vue-html-editor/demo.html")

editable = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="note-editable panel-body"]')
buttonBold = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@data-name="bold"]')
buttonItalic = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@data-name="italic"]')

actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(editable)
actions.click()
actions.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a')
actions.click(buttonBold) 
actions.click(buttonItalic)
actions.perform()

print('HTML Source:')
print(editable.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

# <span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">Hello World!</span>
```